# Changes were pushed on our Git branch and it modified files. However, these commits don't show these files being changed. Does anyone know the cause?

Tags: git

There were commits on our branch which added .ts files. However, it seems that Java files were also changed as well. But the commits for the ts files did not show java files being committed. What could have caused this? I had to revert to a previous commit then manually copy the files from the old commit to the latest?

In the pic below: [Removed]

I checked out Github repository as well, and the java file changes were pushed. But the latest commit pushed to the repository no longer reflects these changes and Github says only ts files were added/modified

Comment: Can you also add descriptive details, like image of files changed, or commit details ?

Comment: Okay, wlll try @Harsh

Comment: Given the message of the *other* commit 9df6..., chances are the merge triggered conflicts with the highlighted commit. As @Gec answered, I would bet that the developper who did the merge resolved the conflict by keeping the changes from that other commit, and discarding the changes you show.

Comment: @LeGEC thank you, Is there a reason why the files that were merge-resolved weren't reflected in the commits?

Comment: @Justin : "conflict resolution" is something that happens locally, on the machine of the person who encounters the conflict. The result of that resolution is simply the content of the merge commit. git alone does not keep a special flag to indicate "this file had a conflict marker" ; at best you may have a list of conflicting files in the commit message.

Comment: @Justin Are you aware that the information (picture blurred and unblurred and all other info in any past version of the post) is still visible? If you need it removed from public you need to contact a moderator/admin. If I understand correctly you removed info to protect privacy (of course a good reason) but nothing a normal user (including those with all privileges) can do will achieve that.

Comment: Please consider adding a sanitized version of the removed info (compare what Gec did) to the question again.

Answer (score 2):

```
* cccccc  -- HEAD, main -- changes made in bbbbbb missing here
* aaaaaa  -- merge commit by user1
|\
| *  bbbbbb - commit by user2 whose changes disappeared
* |  abcdef - commit by user1
|/
* fedcba - parent commit
```

This happened to me a few times, usually when someone who is new to git does a merge and does not understand how it works exactly.

Specifically, they did it an advanced merge using the "ours strategy" (not the "ours recursive option"), like it is described here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging

> If you want to do something like this but not have Git even try to merge changes from the other side in, there is a more draconian option, which is the “ours” merge strategy. This is different from the “ours” recursive merge option.
>
> This will basically do a fake merge. It will **record a new merge commit with both branches as parents, but it will not even look at the branch you’re merging in. It will simply record as the result of the merge the exact code in your current branch**.

Looks like this was the case with the merge commit `aaaaa` (later edited for privacy reasons) done by user1 (later edited username for privacy reasons).

Comment: Okay, thank you for answering. Is there a reason why the 'our strategy' merge did not show in the commits making it seem like no change occurred?

Comment: Hi Gec. Can you confirm that the question, after the deletion of the picture, is still as answerable and useful as it was when you answered? (I ask because the technical details are beyond me....) Not your fault if not, but then please help with convincing OP to keep the question as answered.

Comment: hello, will it be possible for you to delete the usernames mentioned in the reply and the usernames mentioned comments to the reply? i.e. the git username

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, apologies if the answer is off track. I don't think git stores the merge options that were used for the merge, in the merge commits. So it's not possible to figure out exactly how the merge command was run. We can guess though, looking at the outcome, that somehow, "their" changes (made by user2 in commit bbbbbb) were discarded when the merge was made into "our" branch (user1's branch). So the "ours" option must have been used, either as a merge strategy (I think this is more likely) or as a merge recursive option.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think the question is still valid. I added the important bits from the picture at the top of my answer, anonymized, to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Justin done. Added the important bits from the removed pic at the top of my answer with generic names, hashes etc

Comment: @Justin Are you aware that the information (picture blurred and unblurred and all other info in any past version of the post) is still visible? If you need it removed from public you need to contact a moderator/admin. If I understand correctly you removed info to protect privacy (of course a good reason) but nothing a normal user (including those with all privileges) can do will achieve that.